# How can I align an ajax spinner over a knockoutjs templated div

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I am binding certain html templates. Inside the bound div I have an image which is the ajax spinner. This image is never visible I guess because its overriden with the bound template.

Where should I now put this image so it is centered over the div with the bound template?

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" data-bind="template: { name: $root.currentChildTemplate() }">
   <img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax-loader" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either include it in the template, or place it just outside the templated `div`, and set its position absolutely with CSS.

```
<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax-loader" />
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" 
     data-bind="template: { name: $root.currentChildTemplate() }"></div>
```

You could go a step further, and have it only visible when a certain observable is true.

```
<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax-loader" 
     data-bind="visible: ajaxLoading" />
```